# Compare row pair from one table with a row from another table

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables:
Table 1

```
Column A  Column B    Time               
R         T           11/3/14 8:30:00    
A         T           11/3/14 8:35:00
```

Table 2

```
Column A  Column B    Time2           
S         T           11/3/14 8:30:00
U         T           11/3/14 8:32:00
```

I have to write a SQL query which checks for each consecutive row pair in Table 1, if there is a row in table 2 which falls in between. So in this case, 2nd row from table 2 occurs at 8:32 so it falls in between the first 2 rows from table 1.
I have been struggling with this since morning, there are many answers which show how to compare consecutive rows of the same table, but I am not sure how can I compare them with 2nd table.

Desired output is 2nds row of Table 2:
    U         T           11/3/14 8:32:00

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output that you want?  Also, tagging the question with the database is also helpful.

Comment: Which database server are you using? Oracle? SQL Server? Something else?...

Comment: By _row pair_ do you mean 2 consecutive rows when sorted in order of `Time`?

Comment: @ForguesR : Yes. Take rows 1&2 from table 1 and look for record in Table 2 that falls in between them in time. Then take row 3 & 4 from table 1 and repeat...

Comment: What about rows 2 & 3? Why they aren't a pair?

Comment: Look at The Column A in Table 1, the content in them are R for row 1 and A for row 2. That decides why they are pair. The A always follows R in each set of 2 rows. So my row 3 and 4 will be:    Column A  Column B    Time               
R         T           11/3/14 8:40:00    
A         T           11/3/14 8:45:00

Comment: So... for each R followed by A in table 1, you want to find whether there is a record in table 2 that has a time-stamp between the R and the A? Is that right? Does one also need to match on column A or B in Table 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sql server, then for this dataset:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (A VARCHAR(10), B VARCHAR(10), Time1 Datetime)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (A VARCHAR(10), B VARCHAR(10), Time2 Datetime)

INSERT @Table1 VALUES 
    ('R', 'T', '11/3/14 8:30:00'),
    ('A', 'T', '11/3/14 8:32:00'),
    ('R', 'T', '11/3/14 8:40:00'),
    ('A', 'T', '11/3/14 8:42:00')

INSERT @Table2 VALUES 
    ('S', 'T', '11/3/14 8:30:00'),
    ('U', 'T', '11/3/14 8:32:00')
```

you can obtain a table with which you can compare @Table2 by using cross apply:

```
SELECT t1.Time1 AS R_time, t.Time1 AS A_time 
FROM @Table1 AS t1
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.Time1
    FROM @Table1 AS t2
    WHERE A = 'A' AND t2.Time1 >= t1.Time1
) AS t
WHERE A = 'R'
```

The above gives as output:

```
R_time                   A_time
-----------------------------------------------
2014-11-03 08:30:00.000 2014-11-03 08:32:00.000
2014-11-03 08:40:00.000 2014-11-03 08:42:00.000
```

Thus, the final query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Table2 As t3
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT t1.Time1 AS R_time, t.Time1 AS A_time 
    FROM @Table1 AS t1
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 t2.Time1
        FROM @Table1 AS t2
        WHERE A = 'A' AND t2.Time1 >= t1.Time1
    ) AS t
    WHERE A = 'R' 
) t4
WHERE t3.Time2 BETWEEN t4.R_time AND t4.A_time
```

Output:

```
A   B   Time2                   R_time                   A_time
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S   T   2014-11-03 08:30:00.000 2014-11-03 08:30:00.000 2014-11-03 08:32:00.000
U   T   2014-11-03 08:32:00.000 2014-11-03 08:30:00.000 2014-11-03 08:32:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Union the two tables (I am assuming the structures are same) and sort on time. Also, add a field which tells you which table the record is coming from (say a flag which says 0 for table1 and 1 for table 2)
Step2: Find out all records from this union resultset which belong to table2 and has the previous and next record from table2.

Let me know if you need the query for this.